# select2 input field wrap characters around text rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a select2 input text

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <%= f.input_field :lender_id, collection: Lender.all.pluck(:code, :id), class: 'form-control', id: 'select-banker-field', prompt: 'Please Select Banker', disabled: (f.object.new_record? ? false : true ) %>
  </div>
```

[image]

As seen, the input field doesnt show the text label entirely. I want for either the select2 input field width to be auto based on the length of the characters OR for the text to be able to wrap within the input field box.

I know that I can set `width = 100%` or i could change the div to `col-sm-6` and it will show the entire text value but I dont want it that way as i have already defined width but i can compromise on the height

This is my javascript but it still doesnt work

```
$("#select-banker-field").select2({ 

    containerCss : {"display":"block"};

    minimumResultsForSearch: -1
  });
```

Any help appreciated mucho gracias

Comment: you can compromise on height but not on width to show full input field, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @AnilMaurya based on the image u can see that the words r not shown in full. I want the input field box to be able to display it in full